# Changing image opacity in button hover

Tags: html, css

I have an image which has a button on top. Now I need the css to be handling an image opacity which to be applied when I just hover the button.

This is my attempt.

```css
.wwdimg:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  <div><button class="wwdimg"> clickme </button></div>
</div>
```

What happens is that the button opacity changes instead of the image.

Comment: It's only possible if a) both the button and the image share the same parent element and b) the image comes after the button. If you want an example I can provide one in an answer.

Comment: So you mean the button needs to on the top of the image? right? can i ask an example?

Comment: Added an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well with your provided markup this not possible with CSS only...you have to change some of your markup like placing image after button

```css
.wwdimg:hover+img {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="wwdimg">clickme</button>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
</div>
```

If you are not allowed to change HTML part you will need to use javascript

```js
var button = document.querySelector(".wwdimg");
var img = document.querySelector(".image");
button.onmouseover = function() {
  img.style.opacity = ".5";
}
button.onmouseout = function() {
  img.style.opacity = "1";
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  <div><button class="wwdimg">clickme</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you just won by a second

Answer (score 0):

It's only possible if a) both the button and the image **share the same parent element** and b) the **image comes after the button**.

```css
.image-button {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.image-button button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 99;
}

.image-button img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
}

.image-button button:hover + img {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-button">
  <button type="button">Hover me</button>
  <img src="http://placebear.com/400/180"/ >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link for working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Netven/akaqoaz0/17/

```js
    $('.wwdimg').mouseover(function(){
        $('#img_holder').css("opacity", "0.2");
    });
      $('.wwdimg').mouseout(function(){
        $('#img_holder').css("opacity", "1");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<img id="img_holder" width="200px" height="auto" src="https://images.dreamstream.com/prodds/prddsimg/OM_pasteIt8_2_2018_10_0_27495346.jpeg"> 
<div><button class="wwdimg"> clickme </button></div>
</div>
```